# Should we gather up the orphans and give them a proper bur---err... "home"?

Tags: discussion, questions

So, I was playing around with [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/help) queries, and I kind of settled upon questions that have more than five answers, not deleted, not closed, the score is zero and the question asker has gone away for a record attempt at thumb twiddling.

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/776806/orphaned-possible-low-quality-low-hanging-fruit-questions

Should we do something about these 2500 orphans? Downvote, dupe close, closevote, etc...? Or should we let them live their happy little lives?

Comment: Perhaps they just need a Mr Brownlow to come along... :)

Comment: Huh? These search criteria are bizarre; if searching for low-quality questions, why in the world would you eliminate negative-scored questions and limit yourself to questions that *have answers* (which is usually the minimum requirement for them to be useful to anyone in future)? And what difference does it make to the quality of a question how recently its asker has been around? I don't see any reason to think that the class of questions you've identified here is especially problematic, and I'm not sure why you do.

Comment: it's a trend I noticed, that there are a lot of questions that get asked, have a very simple or ambigious problem, get like 10 answers in no time and then never get visited by the question asker again, accepted or upvoted or downvoted. Probaly because it's not bad, it's not good, it's just meh, and people just skip it. usually they are specific problems as in my code not work, gimme code. I elimitnated the rest because then the list would be too long to even glance at.

Answer (score 10):

Just leave them alone. The OP might be long gone, but the question can still be useful to other/future visitors. Of course, if you can improve the questions/answers in any way, or link them to a duplicate question, you're encouraged to do so, but there's no reason to limit yourself to just these posts.

Comment: This goes hand in hand with "vote on content, not on users".